# example of a $B$-bimodule $X$ that is not an $A$-bimodule.

Tags: modules, ideals, banach-algebras

Suppose that $(A, ∥ · ∥_A)$ and $(B, ∥ · ∥_B)$ are two Banach algebras such that $B$
is an ideal in $A$ and $∥·∥_A ≤ ∥·∥_B$. We know that each Banach $A$-bimodule $X$
is also a Banach $B$-bimodule. But the converse is not true in general!

Do you have an example of a $B$-bimodule $X$ that is not an $A$-bimodule, where the $B$-module action on $X$ is the $A$-module action on $X$ restricted to $B$?

Comment: You need to add the requirement that $A$-module action on $X$ restricted to $B$ must coincide with $B$-module action. Otherwise $X$ can always be turned into $A$-bimodule using zero module action.

I think the counterexample is $X=c$, $A=\ell_\infty$, $B=c_0$

Comment: @Norbert Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Norbert Thank you for your comment. I edited the question.